# How to change data during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to multiply and divide the data value during training. How should I try?

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
```

I want to multiply and divide the data at this time.

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same'))
```

Comment: Multiply and divide by what?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Multiply` (and other such operations) layer, as per [this documentation](https://keras.io/layers/merge/). More options are available in [tf.math](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math), including `divide`, just keep in mind that mixing tensorflow keras with pure keras creates problems, so if you use `tf.math` be sure to `from tensorflow import keras` rather than just `import keras`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and accurate answer. This is the information I was looking for!!